# How to use osascript with at to run script at a specific time?

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, automation

I have an AppleScript with the lines:

```
set thisScript to POSIX path of (path to me as text)
do shell script "osascript " & thisScript & " | at now + 1 minute"
```

When it runs, I see the "at" job in queue, but then it never runs the script.

If I type the following into terminal, the script will run:

```
osascript thisScript
```

But when I add the "at" portion, again, it creates the job, but never runs the script.

```
osascript thisScript | at now + 2 minutes
```

How do I get this to work using the "at" command?

EDIT: I'm adding the entirety of my script here just in case there's something in here that would somehow trip up the "at" function.

```
property userpassword : ""

on run
    
    if userpassword is "" then
        display dialog "Please enter your password:" default answer "" with hidden answer
        set userpassword to text returned of result
        -- The repeat section below is an optional error checking routine to ensure the password is valid
        set the_password to "Undefined"
        repeat until the_password is "Correct"
            try
                set theFinderPID to do shell script "ps -axww | /usr/bin/grep '[/]Finder'| awk '{print $1}' | head -1"
                do shell script "renice 1 " & theFinderPID password userpassword with administrator privileges
                do shell script "renice 0 " & theFinderPID password userpassword with administrator privileges
                set the_password to "Correct"
            on error
                display dialog "Sorry, the password entered was not correct. Please try again:" default answer "" with hidden answer
                set userpassword to text returned of result
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    
    do shell script "launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist"
    delay 1
    do shell script "for i in `atq | awk '{print $1}'`;do atrm $i;done"
    delay 1
    
    tell (current date) to set curHour to (its hours as string)
    tell (current date) to set curMin to (its minutes as string)
    
    if curHour + 1 > 23 then
        set newHour to "00"
    else
        set newHour to curHour + 1
    end if
    
    set newTime to newHour & ":" & curMin & ":" & "00" as string
    do shell script "sudo pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU " & newTime password userpassword with administrator privileges
    
    set scriptPath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)
    set thisScript to "'" & scriptPath & "'"
    do shell script "sudo printf %s 'osascript " & thisScript & "' | at now + 1 minute" password userpassword with administrator privileges
    
end run
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138690/discussion-on-question-by-daskraut-how-to-use-osascript-with-at-to-run-script-at).